# Is air resistance totally dependent on surface area?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, projectile, drag, aerodynamics

Two objects of varying mass, but of the same surface area, are dropped from the same height. Which will strike the ground earlier?

Comment: Air resistance does not vary with mass..

Comment: mass has nothing to do with air resistance, with the same surface area and different masses at the same height they hit the ground at the same time.

Comment: @TheBurgerKing you might want to draw a free body diagram for this problem.  In a vacuum, all objects fall at the same rate.  When air resistance is involved, this may not be the case.  Otherwise, an inflated beach ball and a lead ball of the same dimensions would fall together ... which they obviously will not.

Answer (score 4):

to answer the question in the title, the answer is no. *Wetted area drag* depends on the surface area. *Profile drag* depends on the cross-sectional area of the body. *Flow separation drag* depends on the shape of the body.

Comment: What about dependence on air velocity and viscosity/temperature?

Comment: @chet miller, Here I consider only geometrical factors. your mileage may vary and will be lower in california.

Answer (score 0):

$F_{Drag} \rightarrow$ Force due to air resistance

$\rho \rightarrow$ Density of air

$C_{Drag} \rightarrow$ Coefficient of drag

$A \rightarrow$ Cross sectional area

$F_{Drag} = \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 C_{Drag} A$

Air resistance does not depend on the surface area of a body but rather its cross sectional area i.e area perpendicular to the direction of motion.

Air resistance also depends on the velocity of the body.

> Two objects of varying mass, but of the same surface area, are dropped from the same height. Which will strike the ground earlier?

This would be a bit difficult to answer and would require more data.

If you actually meant that both the objects have same cross sectional area, still the drag coefficient of both the objects have to be determined.

Drag coefficient is generally determined experimentally in a wind tunnel where parameters such as wind speed, density can be altered to measure the drag force and calculate the drag coefficient. Hence we can't be sure about which object will hit the ground first.

However, if it was given that both the objects have the same drag coefficient. then the the object with the higher mass would hit the ground first as the acceleration due to air drag would be less when compared to the other.

let the object with more mass be 1 and the one with less mass be 2.
At a particular velocity, the same drag force $F$ will act on both the objects.

$m \rightarrow$ Mass of the object

$a \rightarrow$ Acceleration due to air drag

$A \rightarrow$ Net acceleration

$a_1 = \frac{F}{m_1},\,a_2 = \frac{F}{m_2}$

$m_1>m_2 \implies a_1<a_2$

Since $A = g - a$,

$A_1>A_2$

This means that if both the objects were dropped at the same time, the object with more mass would have a greater acceleration in the downwards direction which would result in it hitting the ground first.

[image: Graph]

This result is supported by this graph which indicates the height vs time of 3 balls of identical sizes. The soccer ball completes the trajectory first followed by the beach ball and the balloon finishes last.

Comment: At high Reynolds number this is often a good approximation. At low Reynolds number, it isn't.